# how do I style a child div in nextjs using css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I am working on the menu bar of a website.

I am using nextjs for my application

I want to style the a tag

but it did not work

My code

Javascript

```
const Nav = () => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.nav}>
            <div className={styles.topNav}>
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <div>
                        <Link href="/">
                            <a>
                                Logo
                            </a>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.navLinks}>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div onClick={openMenu} className={styles.menuHamburger}>Menu</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

CSS

```
.topNav{
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
}

.topNav > div > a{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: What is the actual value of `styles.topNav`? Are you sure it's `"topMenu"`? Also, why do you want to do this with a stylesheet, as opposed to the method you're already using successfully? Further reading: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css

Answer (score 1):

You used the child selector `>` in `.topNav > div > a`, meaning you're only styling an `<a>` that is the child of a `<div>` that is the child of an element with the `.topNav` class. Your `<a>` is only a descendant here. You can use a space instead to specify any descendant: `.topNav > div a`